# Are sort of DevOps code golfing questions appropriate here?

Tags: discussion

An example which comes to my mind for some sort of DevOps golfing is to create mostly lightweight Docker image for given functionality, or a compact Swarm setup for a component with minumum but all required functions.

This in my opinion involves sometimes enough puzzling as well as we know it from code golf; maybe other examples are possible.

My question is - are such DevOps golfing questions appropriate here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there's at least [How to create the smallest working docker image every time?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/413/how-to-create-the-smallest-working-docker-image-every-time) which did get a good reception, I think it's fair to assume they are on-topic for our site.

I won't go to add a [golfing](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golfing) to those question, I think they are on-topic as a practical goal in a devops environment, there's no 'game' behind it.